# Stylelint Nesting Declaration Order Arrays

Tags: css, arrays, stylelint

In [stylelint](http://stylelint.io) is it possible to nest arrays for the rule `declaration-block-properties-order`? I'm curious because I'd really like to have it enforce a declaration order similar to [Nicolas Gallagher's Idiomatic CSS](https://github.com/necolas/idiomatic-css#declaration-order). However I don't really care if padding or margin come first.

I know I can do this easily by having this rule...

```
"declaration-block-properties-order":
    [
      {
        properties: [
          "position",
          "top",
          "right",
          "bottom",
          "left",
          "z-index"
        ],
      },
      {
        order: "flexible",
        properties: [
          "padding",
          "margin"
        ],
      },
    ]
```

However... what I'm looking to do is specify the order for padding and margin groups, so margin, margin-top, margin-right, margin-bottom, and margin-left can only come in this order, same for padding.. but not care which group is first. I've tried nesting the arrays but I'm not sure if this is possible or my syntax was wrong.

```
"declaration-block-properties-order":
    [
       {
        order: "flexible",
        properties: [
          {
            properties: [
              "margin",
              "margin-top",
              "margin-right",
              "margin-bottom",
              "margin-left"
            ],
          },
          {
            properties: [
              "padding",
              "padding-top",
              "padding-right",
              "padding-bottom",
              "padding-left"
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
```

but I don't want it to accept margin, margin-top, padding, margin-right, padding-right. I want the two groups to be organized but not care if the padding or margin group is first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In stylelint is it possible to nest arrays for the rule declaration-block-properties-order?

No, it is not possible.  You have two options:

1. [Write a plugin](http://stylelint.io/developer-guide/plugins/) that offers this flexibility.
2. Require that margin must come before padding, or vice versa, in your CSS code.

I'd recommend the latter option as the more specific your order of properties, the easier it is for team members to know where to look to see if a property is being used within a declaration block.